# Get content between code tag return in array

Tags: php, html

I want to get the content between a code tag in a html document.
I tried forming it in preg_match...
 Could anybody help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use preg_match, do:

```
preg_match("/<code>(.+?)<\/code>/is", $content, $matches);
```

Then access it with

```
$matches[1]
```

Though in general, you are going to find more use and better performance with a HTML Parser, which is the preferred method to Regular Expressions.

Comment: It shows "Unknown modifier 'c' in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\capture-tag.php on line 32" error

Comment: @vinoth Sorry, I forgot the escaping slash ( \ ) in front of the backslash. The code above is updated now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used $html_content = '<code><b>This is test</b></code><h1>hi all Now im fine</h1><br><code><h1>This too test</h1></code>'; while executing for this string the above code give compilation error

Comment: @vinoth I've updated it one more time, I had the wildcard search messed up. (*+?) should be (.+?). Note that using your test value will return an array inside of matches, which you can recover using `foreach($matches[1] as $match)`

Comment: @shmeeps Now I got the ans... Thanks for your help

Comment: @vinoth No problem, sorry for the confusion. Let us know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you use phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) which allow:

```
print qp($html)->find("code")->text();
// looks for the <code> tag and prints the text content
```

If you want to try regular expressions for this, check out some of the tools listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for help.